# Is it possible to get a reasonably priced and safe taxi from Oslo Airport after 11:00 p.m?

Tags: oslo

I'll be having lot of luggage with me and will be arriving in Oslo around 11:00 p.m. Is it possible to get a taxi during late hours? If so, How do I book the taxi (I will have NOK in cash and International Debit Cards) and Is it safe to travel in taxi during late hours?

Edit: Destination is Heimdalsgata, Oslo.

Comment: "The distance between the Oslo Airport Gardermoen and the city center is 48 km"

Comment: The good news is that taxi travel from the airport is safer at all hours (not counting risk outside at your destination, which we don't know), and the bad news is that it is not reasonably priced at any hour.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to get a taxi at those hours. There may be a slightly longer wait than during daytime though. You can either take a taxi from those waiting, or order a taxi from one of the machines. Taxis usually have a fixed price to central Oslo. Ask about that before getting in the taxi. Drivers are legally required to tell you the price if you ask. Expect to pay at least 800-1000 NOK, since it's a rather long trip and Norway is an expensive country. Drivers usually prefer card over cash. Most standard debit cards (Visa, Mastercard) should be accepted. There is a lot of information about taxis on the airport taxi website: [taxiguide](https://taxiguide.no/en/front-page/)

Taxis are safe, as long as it's a legitimate taxi. It should have proper taxi signs and a taxi meter and so on. Only legitimate taxis can be ordered from the machines, and only legitimate taxis can wait at the taxi stand.

As a cheaper alternative, you can take the train to central Oslo and a taxi from there. The airport express leaves every 20 minutes until 00.50 and only costs 190 NOK for an adult. It is designed to be comfortable for people with a lot of luggage. More information here: [airport express](https://flytoget.no/en/)

Comment: Thank you Johanna for providing the information. If I take the train to Oslo central station , Is it possible to get a Taxi from Central Station during late night hours? Is the process of booking the taxi from Central Station  same as you explained for getting a taxi from Airport?

Comment: Beware that the trains do not depart all night. The last train to Oslo departs from the airport 0:50. If you land exactly 23:00, you should usually have time to catch the train. If your plane lands a bit later and there is a delay with the luggage, you can easily be out of luck.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thank you for pointing that out. I added that to the answer.

Comment: You should also mention that Uber is available in Norway.